# How can I import table data into my googlesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

How can I import table from this link https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/oi_spurts.htm , to my google sheet. Please help me out! Highly Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: I tried it but results =N/A, See the formula I used =IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='tabs_main_content']//table/")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider adding some more details to your question. Post the formula you are using for import, and any errors you are getting.

Comment: Do you want to automate the import of this data in Google Sheet? Or do a unique import, in this case a copy/paste of the datagrid displayed in the page will solve your problem?